# NextJS + React + SVG Component - Import Typescript IntrinisicAttribues error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js

I'm trying to directly load SVG elements into a React component, and it's been a massive headache. I'm a bit new to really digging in with understanding. To be fair, I'm really enjoying Next, it reminds me a lot of Ruby or Laravel.

So, perhaps someone can help guide me on the path of enlightenment here... I'm using a Next plugin, withReactSvg

**next.config.js**

```js
module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [
            withReactSvg, {
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib/svg/'),
                webpack(config, options) {
                  return config
                }
            }
        ],
      //[/*plug name*/,  { /* plugin config here ... */ }],
    ],
    {
      /* global config here ... */
      future: {
        webpack5: true,
    },
      distDir: '.build',
    },
  );
```

This plugin extends Next to import SVGs more directly and be able to control internal SVG css more directly, and it's pretty elegant compared with other solutions...

In any component, I can now do the following:

**ExampleComponent.tsx**

```js
import Icon from '../lib/svg/icon_4.svg';

export default function ExampleComponent() {
    return ( <Icon fill="red" stroke="white" /> );
}
```

This code compiles and works, but trying to use Typescript I receive this error:

```
(JSX attribute) fill: string
Type '{ fill: string; stroke: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

The closest I think I've gotten to solving this puzzle is a really good article [React Higher Order Component Patterns In Typescript](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb), but it comes just shy of working because I'm sort of implicitly creating a react component with the import.

A lot of other articles seem to assume I'm trying to do something I shouldn't be doing... And maybe I am?

Comment: Temporary fix `<Icon {...this} fill="red" stroke="white" />`
But this seems really hacky and I'd like to understand the issue better

Comment: I cannot see any problem in the code. The only way this error is going to happen is using `ExampleComponent` in other place e.g. `import Icon from './ExampleComponent` and calling it like `<Icon fill="red" stroke="white" />`. Can you confirm the error is inside or outside of the `ExampleComponent.tsx` ?

Comment: Yep. Inside the component itself.

Comment: can you share your project or make a mini project which has the same error? i cannot simulate the error you get. If you mouse hover `fill`, is there any type hints appear? should be like `(JSX attribute) SVGAttributes<SVGElement>.fill?: string | undefined`

Comment: I'm running typescript 4.2.4 in vscode. I'm not sure that's possible but now you have me thinking it's environmental. I just did a test on codesandbox and nothing. TSX on my end is showing them as JSX Attributes while on the sandbox it's being resolved completely as SVGAttributes. Weird. Maybe a bug?

Comment: I will test the setting tonight. stay tuned

Comment: You already sent me in the right direction. It appears typescript doesn't like when two modules are declared using the same file types and they share a variable name in the local scope such as "value". For that reason, it seems next-images and next-svg-react are incompatible... Thing is, I'm not using next-images anymore but can't figure why it still thinks I am

Comment: Did you remove `/// <reference types="next-images" />` in the next-env.d.ts ? I can simulate your problem if i have the type defined there

Comment: Yep, that was it.

Comment: Cool. case closed